# Extracting Sequences from Multiple Strings

Tags: python, keras, sequence, categorical-data

I'm looking for a solution that helps to structure and analyze sequence data of different length. I need to prepare the data for a machine learning classifier (LSTM). My input example looks as follows:

**Input**

```
ID 1 2 3 4
0  A B C D
1  A C D
2  A D B
```

Where columns are the number of sequence steps and `A,B,C,D,E` certain actions.

As **possible sequences**, we would expect:

```
A,B
B,C
C,D
A,B,C
B,C,D
A,C
A,C,D
C,D
A,D
A,D,B
D,B
```

First, a script should print, **how often certain sequences occur**, and how many sequences exist at all

```
(C,D) 2
(A,B,C,D) 1
(A,B) 1
...
```

But even more important, for later use, I need to **one-hot encode** all potential sequences, so that the final result looks like:

**Desired output**:

```
ID  (A,B) (B,C) (C,D) (A,B,C) (B,C,D) (A,C) (A,C,D) (C,D) (A,D) (A,D,B) (D,B)
0   1     1     1     1       1       0     0       1     0     0    0 
1   0     0     1     0       0       1     1       1     0     0    0
2   0     0     0     0       0       0     0       0     1     1    1
```

Where `(A,B)` `(B,C)` etc. could also be represented as encoded variables. This way, I think, the data would be represented in a form that considers sequences and subsequences for classification.

For the first part, I read about PrefixSpan but could not find replicable code examples. As I'm working with scikit-learn and keras, related solutions are welcome!

**Tried:**

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
d = {'1': ['A', 'A', 'A'], '2': ['B', 'C', 'D'], '3': ['C', 'D', 'B'], '4': ['D', '', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

list(itertools.combinations(df))
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Christopher, this is a probability problem, you need to find out the no of possible outcomes for ABCDE with 2,3 and 4 letters

Comment: Since there is no code attached, I am only going to give a suggestion - Use the [`itertools` package](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html) for permutations or combinations and just use a dictionary as an occurrence counter.

Comment: @Austin I inserted something into the example, though: 1) I'm afraid any approach of myself might be the starting point for solutions that may not be optimal 2) I have no idea where to start and whether there are appropriate packages out there?

Comment: Could you please add your exact Definition of the term `sequence`? I see that it's used as synonym for `combination` here, but I have the Impression, that only direct neighbours are allowed, right? Otherwise e.g. (A,C) would also be a sequence in the first line (index 0)

Comment: `import itertools
print(list(itertools.combinations(df['2'], 1)))
print(list(itertools.combinations(df['2'], 2)))
print(list(itertools.combinations(df['2'], 3)))` But this actually does not print per row, but per column... and I need to apply this to all rows in a df.

Comment: @SpghttCd good point. I am only thinking about direct neighbours. So, `A,C` in the first row would not be allowed, but `A,B,C` would be considered.

Comment: So in other words you're searching for all "from-to"-sublists with minimum length 2 (and max len(row))

Comment: yes, with the maximum length of each the whole row of items and minimum a set of two. I assume all possible sequences per row must be written into a dictionary and then duplicates must be removed. From the dictionary, then all sequences might be counted across the whole df and. Still not sure how to get to the one-hot encoding then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try by putting your steps as strings, sequences as substrings:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_seq(s):
    return [s[a:b] for a in range(len(s)) for b in range(a+2, len(s)+1)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'steps': ['ABCD', 'ACD', 'ADB']})
df['seq'] = df.steps.apply(get_seq)

df
Out: 
  steps                           seq
0  ABCD  [AB, ABC, ABCD, BC, BCD, CD]
1   ACD                 [AC, ACD, CD]
2   ADB                 [AD, ADB, DB]
```

first requested result: **sequence counter**

```
all_seq = df.seq.apply(pd.Series).stack().values

all_seq
Out: 
array(['AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'BC', 'BCD', 'CD', 'AC', 'ACD', 'CD', 'AD', 'ADB', 'DB'], dtype=object)

df_count = pd.DataFrame({'seq': all_seq, 'cntr': 1})

df_count.groupby('seq').count().T            # .T only for shorter output here below
Out: 
seq   AB  ABC  ABCD  AC  ACD  AD  ADB  BC  BCD  CD  DB
cntr   1    1     1   1    1   1    1   1    1   2   1
```

second requested result: **one hot encoded table**

```
df_ohe = pd.DataFrame()
for seq in set(all_seq):
    df_ohe[seq] = df.steps.str.contains(seq)

df_ohe
Out: 
    ABCD    BCD     AC     AB    ABC     AD    ADB     DB     BC    ACD     CD
0   True   True  False   True   True  False  False  False   True  False   True
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False
```

or if you rather like zeros and ones:

```
df_ohe.astype(int)
Out: 
   ABCD  BCD  AC  AB  ABC  AD  ADB  DB  BC  ACD  CD
0     1    1   0   1    1   0    0   0   1    0   1
1     0    0   1   0    0   0    0   0   0    1   1
2     0    0   0   0    0   1    1   1   0    0   0
```

Comment: ...but thinking about it - this should work with any iterable, not only strings.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you. Will wait 1-2 more days for potential alternatives and mark as solved.

Comment: EDIT: removed dependence of `itertools`, added 0/1-representation of one hot encoded table

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_all_subsequence(seq):
    return [seq[i:j] for i in range(len(seq)) for j in range(i + 2, len(seq) + 1)]

input = ["ABCD", "ACD", "ADB"]

counter = Counter()
for entry in input:
    counter.update(get_all_subsequence(entry))
print(counter.most_common())
[('CD', 2), ('AB', 1), ('ABC', 1), ('ABCD', 1), ('BC', 1), ('BCD', 1), ('AC', 1), 
('ACD', 1), ('AD', 1), ('ADB', 1), ('DB', 1)]
```

Comment: This function finds common substrings, but it doesn't find non-contiguous subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get what is restriction to go to next row in output , but you can count the occurrence by dictionaries:

```
data = ['AB',
'BC',
'CD',
'ABC',
'BCD',
'AC',
'ACD',
'CD',
'AD',
'ADB',
'DB']
matrix={}
for i in data:
    if i in matrix:
        matrix[i] +=1 
    else:
        matrix[i] =1

print(matrix)
```

output:{'BCD': 1, 'AD': 1, 'DB': 1, 'AB': 1, 'ABC': 1, 'AC': 1, 'BC': 1, 'ADB': 1, 'ACD': 1, 'CD': 2}

This method is sensitive to the order of inputs. If it does matter then I have to update it

Comment: That already helps for the first part, thank you. But surprised you don't use itertools, because I see it a lot.

Comment: I am newbie in Python too:)